# Multiple Knapsack Problem, but with exact weight/capacity? (All knapsacks have to be filled completely)

Tags: knapsack-problems

I have a few knapsacks of given capacities.

Also, much more items of given weights and values.

As usual, items have to be put into knapsacks to maximize profit.

---

What is different from a standard MKP, is that there’s a requirement
that each knapsack has to be **filled completely**. I.e. the sum of
weights of its items has to be **equal** to its capacity (while in the
standard problem, it is less-than-equal).

---

How to approach this? (I want to find an algorithm to solve this.)

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Show that it is NP-Complete ? Find an algorithm to solve it ?

Comment: @GBat Oh, right, sorry! To find an algorithm. =)